# Make Wise Numbers

Tags: code-golf, number, code-generation, bitwise

[Wise](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Wise) is a simple bitwise language I designed a while back.  It is based around [Python's bitwise operations](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).  It has several operations most of these are the same or very similar to the equivalent symbol in Python.

- `:` Duplicate the top of the stack
- `?` Rotate the top of the stack to the bottom
- `!` Rotate the bottom of the stack to the top
- `[` `]` loop while the top of the stack is not zero
- `~` not the top of the stack (*`-(n+1)`*)
- `-` negate the top of the stack (*`-n`*)
- `>` bitshift the top of the stack once to the right (*`n//2`*)
- `<` bitshift the top of the stack once to the left (*`n*2`*)
- `^` xor the top two items of the stack (*Same as Python*)
- `|` or the top two items of the stack (*Same as Python*)
- `&` and the top two items of the stack (*Same as Python*)

---

Making an integer in Wise is pretty simple you can make zero with `::^` and increment it with `~-` so you make zero and increment it a bunch of times.  However if we remove the `-` things become a little more interesting.

We can still make every number using the remaining operations.  For example here is 3

```
~<<~
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/wise#@19nZ2djU/f/PwA)

This works because `~` turns zero, an infinite string of `0` bits, into negative one, an infinite string of `1` bits,  each `<` appends a `0` bit to the end, when we are done we do `~` which turns each it into a string of `0`s followed by a two `1`s, or as most people call it 3.

---

## Task

Write a program that when given a positive integer will output a Wise program that will create the number `n` without any `-` in its source (the source of the output, you may use `-` in your own source).  You may assume that there is already a zero on the top of the stack.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) *not* [meta-golf](/questions/tagged/meta-golf) so you should aim to minimize the generating source code *not* necessarily the output.

## Example outputs

*This list is not exhaustive they are simply possible outputs*

```
1  -> ~<~
2  -> ~<~<
3  -> ~<<~
4  -> ~<~<<
5  -> ~<~:<<|
6  -> ~<<~<
7  -> ~<<<~
8  -> ~<~<<<
9  -> ~<~:<<<|
10 -> ~<~:<<|<
11 -> ~<<~:><<<|
12 -> ~<<~<<
13 -> ~<<~:<<<|>
14 -> ~<<<~<
15 -> ~<<<<~
16 -> ~<~<<<<
```

Comment: is 0 included in `positive integers`

Comment: No, 0 is not included in positive integers.

Comment: Apparently `:` applied on an empty stack pushes a `0`. I think this should be specified, as it's not obvious that duplicating from an  empty stack should give `0`

Comment: Are other characters syntax errors, or are they ignored?

Comment: @Luismendo you do not know the contents of the stack other than that that too if the stack is a zero

Comment: @xnor they are ignored

Answer (score 8):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 10 bytes

```
¤d0'<1"~<~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@39oSYqBuo2hUp1N3f//JiYA)

Basic idea: take the binary representation of the number, and map `0` to `<` and `1` to `~<~`. Outputs for 1-10:

```
 1: ~<~
 2: ~<~<
 3: ~<~~<~
 4: ~<~<<
 5: ~<~<~<~
 6: ~<~~<~<
 7: ~<~~<~~<~
 8: ~<~<<<
 9: ~<~<<~<~
10: ~<~<~<~<
```

Comment: Metagolfing this would be easy, too. Just strip pairs of `~~`

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```js
f=n=>n?f(n&1?~n:n/2)+'<~'[n&1]:''
```

```html
<input type=number oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Works for any 32-bit integer.

Comment: Ok I figured this out.  Cool! nice job.

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 38 bytes

I feel like PPCG is really improving my Haskell. *Strokes white cat.*

```hs
f n=mapM(["<","~<~"]<$f)[1..n]!!n>>=id
```

`f` takes an `Int` and returns a `String`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#DchNCoMwEAbQq3wGFwpl6PjXCok36AnERWgSCNRpiUp3Xj3tW77VRjFRdp/scy8PeUXxG632UwVK3rqavu/kthwg5r@PalZaXdSpT7XoMtQzE8lSFDJNJrqcGQ1adOgx4IY7RvAVzOAG3II7cA8efg)

(I'm referring to that `<$f` by the way. It saves a character over `\_->`.)

> In the `Functor` instance for `(->) a` (functions from type `a`), we have: `x <$ f = fmap (const x) f = const x . f = const x`. The only limitation is that `f` and the final `const x` must use the same source type `a`. The instance is completely lazy so this never even evaluates `f`.

Alternatively, same length but less evil (`(l!!)` is an anonymous function):

```hs
(l!!)
l=(++)<$>"":tail l<*>["<","~<~"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#BcFLDsIgFAXQuau4fekArCG@/vwEuhHjgFiakFA0FOOsW8dzVuuj8TG7ZF@5/sbgo9vUaj9iUcnZWarfO81bWYwIVSUPwYimkbqeiO7Z@oCgj9ODNJ1o1zs9S2G06NBjwIgLrriBz2AGt@AO3IMH8PgH)

Both of these use the same representation as @ETHproductions' Japt answer, although especially the first one may give some redundant `<`s at the beginning.

The first one calculates all combinations of `n` `"<"` and `"~<~"` strings, then indexes into the resulting list.

The second one recursively calculates an infinite list formed by starting with `""` and then constructing new elements by appending `"<"` and `"~<~"` strings to each element already in the list (actually it was slightly shorter to also let the `""` get turned into `"<"`.)

Comment: How on earth does that `<$f` work? Some weird functor instance?

Comment: @xnor *Mwahahaha* I guess I should add an explanation then.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>118</s> <s>116</s> <s>109</s> <s>107</s> <s>105</s> 91 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to cyoce!

```ruby
->n{o={0=>""}
o.dup.map{|c,k|["~~c","<c*2"].map{|t|o[eval t[1..9]]=k+t[0]}}until o[n]
o[n]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#JcixDoIwEADQna9oblRsgLiYWH7kvBhSwTRgr8HDpS2/XmNc3vAmcyun3kc2sTE9QK5YP7agX0OIydZzQth3CzVc7aED@r8kxvEzLEqw1fpCZOajYEM5b17cohg9VT9yCavzoiZ8jvLWwndH5dx2Xw)

This is a function that takes the integer as input and returns the string that represents that integer in Wise. You can find an ungolfed version **[here](https://gist.github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/771c36bf38a714c98816c528750d7a7b)**, which tests this program on all integers from 1 up.

The basic idea is to record a "pool" of constants. Then, with each "step", constants are added to the pool for each possible function. I have chosen the functions `~`, `<`, and `>`, which I believe are sufficient to represent every number. (At least, every number under 10,000.)

Comment: You can use `dup` instead of `clone` iirc

Comment: Do you even need `dup`? `map` doesn't modify its receiver.

Comment: @Cyoce I think it does

Comment: Oh I see now. Ruby doesn't like modifying while iterating.

Answer (score 3):

## Python2, <s>54</s> <s>52</s> 51 bytes.

```
lambda x:'<'.join('>~<~'*int(i)for i in bin(x)[2:])
```

Thanks to Wheat Wizard for saving 2 bytes, and Ørjan Johansen for one byte! This uses the same idea as ETHproduction's Japt answer, but with different replacement strings (i.e. using the binary representation)

Comment: You don't need the `[` `]` around the generator inside of the `join`.  `join` can take a generator as its argument.

Comment: I think `'>~<~'*int(i)` may save you a byte.

Comment: I believe the newest score is supposed to be listed last, for the benefit of automated scoreboard snippets and the like.

Comment: There, sorry about being late on that.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
bS'<…~<~‚èJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@58UrG7zqGFZnU3do4ZZh1d4/f9vAgA)

Similar to ETHproductions' Japt answer.

Saved 4 bytes thanks to @Adnan!

Comment: Hey nice! You don't actually need to convert the numbers to strings as they are equal 'types' in 05AB1E. Same for the number literals (you can do without the `'`). You can also use indexing, which should give you [11 bytes](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@58UrG7zqGFZnU3do4ZZh1d4/f9vAgA) :).

Comment: @Adnan Thank you very much!

Comment: @Adnan Just a quick question, how does è work here?

Comment: First, it swaps the arguments because it would run into an exception if it was evaluated normally. After swapping, it maps `0` to the zeroth element and `1` to the first element (because it vectorizes automatically). [Here](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@6@UmJSckpqmdGjT4RX//0cb6igY6SgYxwIA) is a more clear example of how it works.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>123</s> 110 bytes

```python
def w(x):a=map(int,bin(x)[2:]);return x%2*("~<~:<"+"<".join(":"*e for e in a[-2::-1])+"|"*sum(a))or w(x/2)+"<"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FY3BCsIwEER/ZVkQsqlVsl5kjV9SeoiYQoSmJbbYg/TX43p9M2@mPuMAH7ORhPsYZpPycnykrKBj6elW4rKWDNuBrcHd7@KxQY@n16QlFLQRhqlAhJQhdC2LtK6nBr9o3@toApGmun9m@nt1LvqgwF346pjqDw)

Also as a `lambda`

```python
w=lambda x:x%2*("~<~:<"+"<".join(":"*int(e)for e in bin(x)[-2:2:-1])+"|"*sum(map(int,bin(x)[2:])))or w(x/2)+"<"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#LcxBCsIwEIXhq4QBYSa1SsaNDPEk0kWKFSImLa3SLKRXjyO4/fneq@vlGVJ/C6ZI2bFF2PwmHhrwcHiMMSMI2JhfONB9nM1gYja95kLXloWldR018AG7vBOmMKHa/R@wdESkqxXLken3WadZgQZ34rNjql8)

Could be shorter but here is my solution. It takes the binary representation and turns it into the code.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 23 bytes

```
?Uu ?ß~U +'~:ßU/2 +'<:P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@28fWqpgf3h@XaiCtnqd1eH5ofpGQJaNVcD//2YA)

Answer (score 0):

## Jelly, <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
Bị“~<~“<”F
```

This is a ported version of ETHproductions' Japt answer. Speaking of ETHproductions, they saved me one byte!

Comment: Could you swap the strings and pretend the indexing is 0-based?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm referring to the fact that I have to increment the binary representation of the number to get usable indexes.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@/0cHf3o4Y5dTZ1QNLmUcNct///TQz@m5gAAA "Jelly – TIO Nexus")

Comment: Doesn't work, 1 produces `<`, which in Wise produces 0

Comment: Really? [It gives `~<~` for me](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@/0cHf3o4Y5dTZ1QNLmUcNct////xsCAA "Jelly – TIO Nexus")

Comment: OK, thanks for that!

Comment: Oh, I see how it works now! Modular indexing, which was added recently, right?

Comment: I think it's been there from the start, actually